# ‘I spent three months’ vs ‘I spent three months of time’

Tags: difference

> I spent three months

vs

> I spent three months of time

Are these two sentences interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ‘I spent three months.'

> ‘I spent three months of time.'

Both examples mean the same.  The 'of time' is redundant and should be deleted.

"I spent three months' time" is also possible.

Comment: I don't consider 'I spent three months time' to be idiomatic. You might say "'I spent three months of my time...' if if you wanted to stress that you had given up your own time to help somebody.